# binding location on map in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to bind images on locations on map in windows phone 8.1:

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="RestoMap" MapServiceToken="" Height="520" Margin="0,50,0,0" Width="380" ZoomLevel="8">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapIcons" >
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="DarkSlateBlue" Width="170" Height="170">
                        <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding picture}" Width="150" Height="100" Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding location}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>
    </Maps:MapControl>
```

Code: the image didn't appear on map any help

```
{
double latitude = ....;
double longitude = ....;
Location location = new Location();
location.Latitude = latitude;
location.Longitude = longitude;
locations.Add(location);
}
MapIcons.ItemsSource = this.locations;
```

Comment: What is `Maps:MapControl`? Which (third party) control do you use?

Comment: Maps:MapControl used in order to display the map

Comment: the Image control's source is bound to a property named `picture`, but the `Location` class does not define a `picture` property.

Answer (score 0):

The binding is wrong.

According to your XAML, the class should have these **two properties**, one is `picture` to show the image, and the other is `location` to set the image location on the map. I rename them as `MapPicture` and `MapLocation` to follow the CamelCase naming convention.

The class:

```
class MapIcon
{
    public ImageSource MapPicture { get; set;}
    public Location MapLocation { get; set; }
}
```

and the updated XAML-just rename the 2 properties:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Background="DarkSlateBlue" Width="170" Height="170">
        <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding MapPicture}" Width="150" Height="100" Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding MapLocation}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And how you bind a collection of MapIcon's to the `MapItemsControl`.

```
ObservableCollection<MapIcon> icons = new ObservableCollection<MapIcon>();  

private void ShowMapIcons()
{
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(....);
    double latitude = ....;
    double longitude = ....;
    Location location = new Location();
    location.Latitude = latitude;
    location.Longitude = longitude;
    MapIcon icon = new MapIcon() { MapLocation = location,  ImageSource = img };

    icons.Add(icon);

    MapIcons.ItemsSource = icons;
}
```

Comment: the image is displayed away from the binded location

Comment: that is another question, I can help you with the binding, but I can't debug this, that needs more context.